# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `user_id`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I've got a schema with leagues

```
  create_table "leagues", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",                           null: false
    t.date     "start_date",                     null: false
    t.date     "end_date"
    t.string   "day"
    t.string   "start_time",                     null: false
    t.integer  "practice_length",                null: false
    t.integer  "alley_id",                       null: false
    t.integer  "frequency",                      null: false
    t.integer  "scratch",          default: 220
    t.integer  "handicap_percent", default: 80
    t.integer  "handicap_round",   default: 0
    t.integer  "occurrences",                    null: false
    t.integer  "user_id",                        null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
  end
```

and models

```
class Alley < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  has_many :leagues
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leagues
end

class League < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :alley
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :teams
end
```

and factory

```
factory :league do
  name Faker::Company.name
  start_date start_date
  end_date end_date
  day Date.today.day
  start_time '7:00pm'
  practice_length 10
  frequency 1
  occurrences weeks

  association :alley, factory: :alley
  association :user, factory: :user
end

factory :user do
  email 'test@example.com'
  password 'Test1234'
  password_confirmation { 'Test1234' }
end

factory :alley do
  name Faker::Company.name
  association :address, factory: :address
end
```

When I try to create a league, I get an error

> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
>      can't write unknown attribute `user_id`

It's set up exactly like alley, and alley works.  A league should be assigned to an alley and assigned to a user.  An alley can have many leagues and a user can have many leagues. Frankly, I'm too tired to figure out why this isn't working currently.

Comment: Could you update the factory for `user`?

Comment: Yes, I can update it, to what?

Comment: Yup, I just wanna see it clearer, btw, you may recheck the `user_id` in your schema, `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError` indicates like `user_id` is missing!

Comment: You can do rake db:reset

Answer (score 3):

I had been modifying migrations (as I'm getting the initial dataset up), I migrated down, then up.  That what got me where I was.  I had to drop the database and then run setup.  Something must have been stale.

Comment: Want to verify your assumption. If you create a migration without an index, migrate forward, add the index (or reference) to the migration file, migrate or rollback, migrate forward again, you're messed up. Rails team doesn't see this as an acceptable use case so don't expect a fix.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my tests were failing. Thanks to @TIMBERings answers I was able to narrow it down.

> If you create a migration without an index, migrate forward, add the
>   index (or reference) to the migration file, migrate or rollback,
>   migrate forward again, you're messed up

To Fix my failing RSpec tests I ran the following and reran the tests and it passed.

```
rails db:reset RAILS_ENV=test
```

You could also simply run

```
rails db:reset
```